# Do I need both copies of my printer (Brother DCP J715W) on Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, drivers, network-printer, brother-printer

I'm moving to a new computer and I freshly installed a Brother package of drivers and utilities for my printer/mfp.

Somehow there is already my printer and a copy of it, both functional, as I was able to print the test page on both. From those test pages I assume that there are two types of drivers installed now - Brother DCP-J715W Printer and Brother IJ Leg Type2 Class Driver.

Do I need to keep both copies and both driver types to print and use scanner?

Comment: Probably not, and it might be safe to remove the older legacy driver... however, they probably take up very little room, and it would do no harm to leave them.

Comment: IMHO, no harm to uninstall.. just keep the one with the latest version of driver.

Answer (score 0):

One is automatically installed by the system, and the other is installed by the driver of the printer. Usually we can keep a printer.

We can check if the printer ports of the both printer copies are the same in printer properties.

If their printer ports are the same, we keep Brother DCP-J715W Printer and delete the other one.

If their printer ports are different, we keep the printer that works well by our testing(It is best to keep Brother DCP-J715W Printer).